# Clear entire back stack

Tags: android, stack, back, activity-finish

Is there any way to clear the entire back stack and kill the application on ICS in the same way as finishAffinity() does on JB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, as finishAffinity() was introduced in JB in order to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result by keeping track of your activities somewhere as they are created (in `onCreate()`) and when you want to clear the stack you iterate through the activites and call `finish()` on each of them. Make sure you remove the activities you are keeping track of in their `onDestroy()` method too, otherwise you'll leak the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding launchMode="singleTask"